# In R: Gravity model; how to handle vectorized data from symmetrical matrix?

Tags: r, generalized-linear-model, matrix

I have vectorized data from a symmetrical matrix with collaboration data.

So the collaboration between *country i* and *country j* is the same as between *country j* and *country i*.

I deleted the principal diagonal.

I run a GLM in R (package glm2) with the following code. I assume a Poisson distribution because of the dependent variable is count data; I count how many collaborations (or connections) two countries have.

```
gm <- glm(collaborations~ size_i + size_j + distance_ij, family=poisson(link="log"), data=data)
```

Reading the results, I find the *degrees of freedom* to be very high. This made me wonder if I did something wrong.

I have vectorized the symmetrical matrix (using `as.vector`), resulting in an array that holds information on the collaboration between *country i* and *country j*, but also on *country j and i*. As the matrix is symmetrical, these values are the same.

Is this troublesome? Should I run the model on only 50% of the observations?

Any help or pointers are more than welcome. Thanks!

Comment: For what truly tiny countries is trade measured by *counting* indivisible items? Indeed, exactly *what* is being counted? If country X ships apples and oil in return for oranges and spices, how would counts of anything make any sense at all in measuring trade?

Comment: @whuber, this is a hypothetical case. Here I am interested in the problems that might occur from having so many "double" observations and how that might interfere with the GLM.

Comment: Thank you. I'm not sure what a "double" observation is. When you have one number representing one particular instance of something, that's one observation. Just because you might find it convenient to *store* each observation twice within an array does not make it into two independent observations! In this particular case, each observation appears to be associated with an *unordered* pair of "countries." What, then, do "size_i" and "size_j" represent? Although their *sum* (or any other symmetric function) may be well-defined, individually they are not uniquely identified by any observation.

Comment: @whuber, Thanks for responding. Great point you make. I slightly altered my question. Hope this makes a little more sense. Size represents the number of firms in country i.

Comment: The problem is that although you know that *one* of {size_i, size_j} is the number of firms in one country and the *other* is the number in the other country, that's not enough to pin down either variable. Thus trying to assign separate coefficients to the sizes makes no sense. It would make sense to use, say, |size_i+size_j|, |size_i-size_j|, min(size_i,size_j), or max(size_i,size_j) as variables in your model, because all of these are symmetric functions of the two sizes.